# using symfony serializer groups didnt' work as well

Tags: symfony, deserialization, slim-4

I'm developping an application with slim4 framework with php8.3.
I installed symfony serializer to serialize/deserialise my objects.

this is how i created the serializer like a dependency:

dependencices.php

```
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
        Serializer::class => function () {
            $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
            $extractors = new PropertyInfoExtractor([], [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()]);
            $normalizers = [new ArrayDenormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, $extractors)];

            return new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        }
    ]);
```

this is my entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Entity;

use App\Application\Repository\CompanyRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[Entity(repositoryClass: CompanyRepository::class), Table(name: 'companies')]
class Company
{
    #[Groups(['save-company'])]
    #[Column(type: 'string', length: 9, nullable: true)]
    private string $siren;

    #[Groups(['save-company'])]
    #[Column(type: 'string', length: 15, nullable: true)]
    private string $siret;

    #[Column(name: 'trading_name', type: 'string', length: 50, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $tradingName;


    public function getSiren(): string
    {
        return $this->siren;
    }

    public function setSiren(string $siren): void
    {
        $this->siren = $siren;
    }

    public function getSiret(): string
    {
        return $this->siret;
    }

    public function setSiret(string $siret): void
    {
        $this->siret = $siret;
    }

    public function getTradingName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tradingName;
    }

    public function setTradingName(?string $tradingName): void
    {
        $this->tradingName = $tradingName;
    }

}
```

this is how i'm deserializing my object:

```
$this->sfSerializer->deserialize(json_encode($this->getFormData()), Company::class, JsonEncoder::FORMAT, [
            AbstractNormalizer::OBJECT_TO_POPULATE => $company,
            AbstractNormalizer::GROUPS => ['save-company']
        ]);
```

this is the body of the request:

```
{
        "siren": "SRN-1",
        "siret": "SRT-1",
        "tradingName": "my comany name"
}
```

**what i want is that the serializer to deserialize only siren and
siret, but it deserialize all the attributes.
what i'm missing?**

Answer (score 0):

Try using the #Ignore attribute in your entity on the field you don't want to be serialize :

```
#[Column(name: 'trading_name', type: 'string', length: 50, nullable: true)]
#[Ignore]
private ?string $tradingName;
```

Comment: but in another action i will serialize it

Comment: have you tried to use the context of the serializer ? https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/components/serializer.html#option-2-using-the-context

Comment: yes it works, but i want to know how to use groups for deserialization

Comment: To be honest with you, i've noticed some weird/hard to explain behaviours using the groups... that's the reason why i mainly use either the serializer context or the ignore attribute.